# Is "1" + 1 correct in PHP?

Tags: php, math

May I write:

```
"1" + 1;
```

In PHP, to get 2, or do I have to cast first:

```
(int)"1" + 1;
```

? The reason I wonder this is because I have a counter in a text file that I want to increment:

```
file_put_contents($filename, file_get_contents($filename) + 1);
```

Comment: @JohnConde Yes, it works, as I said to get 2

Comment: I would avoid to relay on auto conversions, an explicit int cast is better IMHO.

Comment: if this `"1" + 1;` works, then it will work for your last statement as well

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PHP cast string or char to integer itself, if the string is  convertible to integer i.e,

```
"86"+6=92 and "91"+"9"=100 and "91a"+"8"=99
```

But `for "a"+6=6 and "a5"+5=5 and "a"+"a"=0`

php can't cast "a5" to integer, so it cast it as 0 in integer same for "a"

Php is very loose scripting language